# Compare attributes title to url params

Tags: jquery

I have a small plugin from the net to fetch url params:

```
$.extend({
    getUrlVars: function () {
        var vars = [],
            hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    },
    getUrlVar: function (name) {
        return $.getUrlVars()[name];
    }
});
```

This extracts params from url, e.g.:

```
http://mysite.com/page?slideshow=video&title=General Overview
```

I want to match the title param to an existing link which has the same title as the param "title", and do something if match found, in this case General Overview:

```
<a href="/some-colorbox-page" class="colorbox" title="General Overview">View video</a>


        var isSlideshow = $.getUrlVar('slideshow');
        if (isSlideshow === 'video' && $('a.colorbox', '.video').length) {
            var titleAttr = $('a.colorbox').attr('title');
            var title = $.getUrlVar('title');
            $(window).bind('load', function () {
                if (titleAttr  === title) {
                  $('a.colorbox', '.video').each(function()) {
                     $(this).trigger('click');
                  });
                }
            });
        }
```

But this doesn't work.

Shortly, when a visitor visit the link `(http://mysite.com/page?slideshow=video&title=General Overview)`, I want to trigger an event click to an element that has the same title as the value of url param "title".

Note the white space between General and Overview. This thing makes the query a bit complicated. I can not control the title attributes, but may control the title param.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
title = decodeURIComponent(
    (RegExp('title=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
);
$('a[title='+title).trigger('click');
```

#### Tested fully works

Comment: There's a quote mismatch and it's extremely inefficient since it has to loop over every single element on the page. But ok, the latter is not solvable without adding classes/ids...

Comment: Apart from quotes issue, this doesn't work for params with a whitespace (General Overview). Thanks

Comment: @ThiefMaster, Fixed the quote problem, but about the selection, not sure how to do it.

Comment: Maybe add a preceding `a` to at least limit it to the links on the page?

Comment: @Swan, tested the code, changed the approach, check the update

Comment: Yes, perfect. Please kindly correct the element line: $('a[title="' + title + '"]').trigger('click');

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var title = $.getUrlVar('title'),
      slideshow = $.getUrlVar('slideshow');
  if (slideshow === 'video') {
    $('a[title="' + title + '"]').click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, it might make sense to output the value of `title` to check that it's what you're expecting. I notice that `$.getUrlVar` isn't stripping URI encoding at present...